# Is there a way to find where node loads a module from?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to find path to a module after it's been required?

So my problem is - I start node repl, and `require('stylus')` it loads it from somewhere.

I did `npm cache clean`, `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm uninstall -g stylus`, etc. yet it still successfully loads it from somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `require.resolve('stylus')`.  That will give you the path to the module, but will not import it.

So in the REPL.

```
> require.resolve('stylus');
```

You can also reference `module.filename` from inside the module itself if you ever have the need for that.

Comment: how do I do it from within REPL?

Comment: module.filename only works from inside the module.  So I changed the answer.

Comment: Keep the `module.filename` part too and explain where it does and doesn't work. It's still relevant and interesting.

Comment: Awesome! Love Node! Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Thanks @Rudie.  I'll do that.